# Which TFX orchestrator is de facto tandard for TFX?

Tags: tensorflow, airflow, kubeflow, tfx

I am beginner with tensorflow and now in a project where I need to deploy *distributed* production platform for tensorflow. I appreciate if I could get some help to clarify my thought.

Reading the [online doument](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide#required), and [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-VxHnkCJ5Y),
I understood that main components for distributed production are below.

TFX (Tensorflow extended) built with python 3.x
Pipeline: `Apache Beam`
Orchestrator: `Apache Airflow` or `Kubeflow`

However for *orchestrator*, I assume that there are pros and cons for both components but which one is the *de facto standard* for `TFX` ?

The guide mainly focus in `Airflow` so I thought this might be the one but `kubeflow` seems to be *new* so it might be the new challenger.

```
Note: The current revision of this user guide primarily discusses deployment on a bare-metal system using Apache Airflow for orchestration.
```

Thanks,
Yu

Comment: It actually depends on your use case and if you are making deployments of machine learning (ML) workflows on Kubernetes (production environment) Kubeflow is recommended as it is simple, portable and scalable.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kubernetes/Kubeflow is the best orchestrator, however, it brings a lot of upfront costs in setting up and managing your own cluster.

Google just released VertexAI pipelines which is a managed (serverless) service where GCP manages Kubernetes under the covers for you and you can just focus on writing pipeline code.

I highly recommend using it as if very affordable and straight forward to set up. https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/introduction

In my company we saved millions of dollars in operational and maintenance costs by using VertexAI pipelines.

Just to complete this answer, there are some cons associated with VertexAI. It is a Pre-GA offering so there are still some small issues here and there that I run into but I would say its 90% functional and we are using it to orchestrate our end-to-end machine learning workflows as well as automating some of our analytics and data validation workloads.